# Show that $V_ky$ is differentiable at the origin for each continuous fonction y, where $V_ky(t)=\int_{0}^tk(t,s)y(s)ds$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $y\in C([0,a])$ and let $k(.,.)$ be a scalar-valued function that is continuous on 
$$\Delta_a=\{(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq s\leq t\leq a\}$$

Consider the Volterra type operator:
$$V_ky(t)=\int_{0}^tk(t,s)y(s)ds$$

I would like to show that  **$V_ky$  is differentiable at the origin**.

I tried to show that the limit
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{V_ky(h)-V_ky(0)}{h}\quad\text{exists}$$
Since $V_ky(0)=0$, it suffices to show the existence of the limit $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{V_ky(h)}{h}$

Can I say that since $V_ky(h)\to0$ and $h\to 0$ with $h'=1\neq0$, we have that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{V_ky(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(V_ky)'(h)}{1} =\lim_{h\to0}(V_ky)'(h)$$

If the derivative is continuous at the origin, we obtain that: 
$$\lim_{h\to0}(V_ky)'(h)=(V_ky)'(0)$$

Is that correct?

Otherwise, how can I prove the existance of such a limit 
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{0}^tk(h,s)y(s)ds}{h}? $$

Any help please?

Comment: what is the specific form of $k(x,y)$?

Comment: $$k(t,s)=-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n p_k(t)(t-s)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$

Comment: @OliverDiaz The functions $p_k$ are scalar valued functions that are continuous on the interval $[0,a]$

Comment: Without some additional smoothness on $p_k$ ($p_k(0)=0$ and Lipschitz for instance) I doubt you can exchange the limit an integral.